# Issue with Python Torch + Ansible

Tags: pip, pytorch, ansible, bitbucket

We are receiving the error "FILENAME.tar.gz (hidden due to privacy) on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option" when trying to run our pipeline on Bitbucket via Ansible.

We have made no changes to the pipeline, the ONLY change made is that torch (version 2.1.2) has been added as a requirement. We have removed torch again and confirmed that the error was bypassed when we avoided torch.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be the reason for this? Naturally, we are using torch successfully in our local environments, and installing it does not mess with the current directory, so it would make since that the location of the directory did not change.

I am fairly new to ansible, so any pointers would be a godsend.

The ansible line it is failing on is using ansible.builtin.unarchive. This is the first step in our deployment following the completion of the build. Here's the line in ansible for context.

```
name: Extract application
become: true
ansible.builtin.unarchive:
    src: ../filename.tar.gz
    dest: "{{ root }}
    creates : "{{ new }}"
    owner: user1
    group: user1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Noting that my way around this was installing torch as a step in ansible, rather than a step in the requirements. Not the cleanest answer but it did what we needed.

Comment: > _has been added as a requirement._ - to where exactly? What installs your requirements? Please add some context on your execution environment and what do you do before calling the playbook. Adding the full playbook code will also lit some light on what's going on, otherwise it would be guessing. Thank you.